# Aren't there a Qt control styles for android?

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

Aren't there ready made Android styles to use with Qt quick controls or I have to design them on my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no builtin theme for Android with QtQuickControls just yet if that is what you mean. However, the widget gallery example shows that it is not difficult to create something like this for Android:

[image]